# TRESTRequest JSON POST issue in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I'm trying to send JSON POST request to an API using a TRESTClient (Delphi 10.4/Windows 10), but I'm receiving a **409 conflict indicating "No input found"**. Using the same code in (Delphi XE6/Windows 10) I get a **REST request failed: Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.**. Using WireShark I was able to see that Delphi XE6 was sending the request with TLS 1.0 and Delphi 10.4 is using TLS v1.2. The API service accepts only TLS v1.2. Is there a way to use these REST components in Delphi XE6 to deliver the request with TLS 1.2?

I beleived my problem was that I was JSON encoding all the input with the code:

```
// Assign JSON
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.Add('locations=[{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]');
```

and then assigning it to the Request Body with `RESTRequest.AddBody(sl);`, whereas the API only expects the value of the locations parameter to be JSON.
I have updated the code to assign the JSON to a String and used the `RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].name := 'locations';` and `RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].Value := s;` to add the string to the request body.

Here's my updated code:

```
procedure TMainForm.btn_RouteXL_PostClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, sResult, AError: String;
  jsObj: TJSONObject;
  AJSONValue, jsResponse: TJSONValue;
  AParameter: TRESTRequestParameter;
  AStatusCode: Integer;

begin
  //ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;

  s := '[{"address":"Test1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"Test2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"Test3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"},{"address":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","lat":"51.589548","lng":"5.432482"}]';

  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.routexl.com/tour';
  RESTClient.ContentType := 'ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED';
  RESTClient.Authenticator := HTTPBasic_RouteXL;

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem; //Adds a new Parameter Item
  RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].name := 'locations'; //sets the name of the parameter. In this case, since I need to use 'locations=' on the request, the parameter name is locations.
  RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].Value := s; //Adds the value of the parameter, in this case, the JSON data.
  RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED; //sets the content type.
  RESTRequest.Params.Items[0].Kind := pkGETorPOST; //sets the kind of request that will be executed.

  RESTRequest.Execute;

  try
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('************JSONText*******************');
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add(RESTResponse.JSONValue.ToString);
    //Memo1.Lines.Add('JSONValue  :'+RESTResponse.JSONValue.Value);
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('StatusText :'+RESTRequest.Response.StatusText );
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('StatusCode :'+IntToStr(RESTRequest.Response.StatusCode ));
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('ErrorMesage:'+RESTRequest.Response.ErrorMessage);
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('************Content*******************');
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add(RESTRequest.Response.Content);
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('************Headers*******************');
    memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add(RESTRequest.Response.Headers.Text);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('************Error*******************');
      memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('Error : ' +E.Message);
      memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add(E.ClassName);
      memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('************Error*******************');
      memo_ResponseData.Lines.Add('Error : '+RESTResponse.Content);
    end;
  end;

end;
```

I'm able to get it to work in Postman using a key-value pair, by assigning the key as locations and the value as the contents of `sl` as seen in the screenshot. But I'm unable to translate that to Delphi.

[image]

Comment: Normally the `ContentType` for JSON is `application/json`

Comment: @R.Hoek - I added a Postman screenshot showing it working. The API service indicated that the request `ContentType` needed to be `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: You can't post raw JSON as-is using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type, JSON is not a compatible format for that type. As your POSTMAN screenshot shows, the data needs to be posted in `name=value` format instead, where the `name` is `'locations'` and the `value` is the JSON. You need to do the same in your Delphi code, eg: `sl.Add('locations=[{...},...]');`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That's the way I originally had it, but it didn't work. Anyway, I edited the code above again to put it back that way. I noticed there are four different ways in which you can specify the value for the body parameter of your request. Am I missing a parameter in the `RESTRequest.AddBody(sl);`?

Comment: Hmm, the correct `ContentType` string for form data is normally `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. Your using a completely different string (something starting with ‘ct’)

Comment: @R.Hoek - Yes, to my understanding `ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED` is the parameter that Delphi uses for the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,  "multipart/formdata" (e.g. for file-transfer etc.).

Comment: I suspect it’s a constant, but you’re passing it a string data. Try removing the quoted ('') around the ct value and try to compile your code. When it doesn’t compile, I suspect you’ll need to add the official content type string as the ‘ct’ constant does not exist in your delphi version...

Comment: @R.Hoek - You are correct, as there are some differences in parameters for the REST components between the Delphi version (10.4 vs I was testing) and (Delphi XE6). As best I can tell it appears to come down to vXE6 not supporting TLS v1.2 whereas v10.4 does.

Comment: @Hackbrew well, good to know you found the problem. But regarding TLS 1.2.... I use my own http client based on wininet and send my own created json messages, so never had any problem regarding that.